# NASM, macro or subprogram for exponents?

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

So let me qualify this by saying that I'm very new to NASM.

I'm converting a hexadecimal string into a decimal number. I have most of my program running and I've run into a section of my C code which I can't figure out how to write in assembly. I have the size of my string in CL, and I have the integer value of the hexadecimal character saved in AL.

What I want to do is 16^CL * (integer value) and then add that value to EAX (since we only have to do strings of size 4, I can always get my values to fit in EAX).

I've been working on this one part of the program for a couple hours now and I seem to be stumped (other then just hard coding 4096 for the first, 256 for the second... ect, which I hate having to resort to).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any exponent function to convert a hex/binary string to a number. Just multiply by 16 repeatedly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long hex2num(const char* hex)
{
  unsigned long long result = 0;

  while (*hex != '\0')
  {
    char b = *hex;

    if (b >= 'a' && b <= 'f') b = b - 'a' + 10;
    else if (b >= 'A' && b <= 'F') b = b - 'A' + 10;
    else b = b - '0';

    result = result * 16 + b;
    hex++;
  }

  return result;
}

const char* const testData[] =
{
  "0",
  "f",
  "1F",
  "Ffff",
  "FFFFFFFF",
  "7fffffffffffffff"
};

int main(void)
{
  unsigned i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(testData)/sizeof(testData[0]); i++)
    printf("\"%s\" = %llu\n", testData[i], hex2num(testData[i]));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
"0" = 0
"f" = 15
"1F" = 31
"Ffff" = 65535
"FFFFFFFF" = 4294967295
"7fffffffffffffff" = 9223372036854775807
```

Note also that multiplication by 16 is equivalent to shifting 4 binary positions left and that the addition of `b` can be replaced by a bit-wise OR.

Comment: This is so much simpler then what I wrote. I compiled my program and ran it in C and spent my time trying to translate it to assembly. Not sure if that's the right way to go about it.